# Where() with Replace() in Dictionary.Where(p => p.Key is T)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dictionary, web-controls

I have a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Web.UI.Control, object>` where all keys can be either type of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink` or type of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label`.

I want to change `Text` property of each control. Because HyperLink doesn't implement (why?!) `ITextControl`, I need to cast Label or HyperLink explicitly:

```
Dictionary<Control,object> dic = ..

dic
  .Where(p => p.Key is HyperLink)
  .ForEach(c => ((HyperLink)c).Text = "something")

dic
  .Where(p => p.Key is Label)
  .ForEach(c => ((Label)c).Text = "something")
```

Are there ways to workaround such approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a class that derives from HyperLink and let your class inherit from ITextControl. Should be clear where to go from there...

Answer (score 5):

Slightly more elegant, but retaining the problem:

```
foreach (HyperLink c in dic.Keys.OfType<HyperLink>())
{
    c.Text = "something";
}

foreach (Label c in dic.Keys.OfType<Label>())
{
    c.Text = "something";
}
```

Comment: Is it really a problem, though?

Comment: @Isaac Cambron: It iterates the collection twice and performs a lot of type checks, so I'd say it's somewhat ugly. My vote is on the solution by @Stefan Egli.

Answer (score 2):

```
dic.ForEach(c => c.Key.GetType()
    .GetProperty("Text")
    .SetValue(c.Key, "Something",null));
```

Total hack, probably not efficient, but it should work....

**EDIT:** Another thing worth mentioning, if you're using .Net 4, you can use duck typing:

```
dic.ForEach(kvp => ((dynamic)kvp.Key).Text = "Something");
```

Comment: @abat - ... or in other words "probably not efficient"

Answer (score 2):

This way looks uglier and clumsier, but at least you're only enumerating over the dictionary one time:

```
dic
  .ForEach(
    c => {
      var clink = c as Hyperlink;
      if (clink != null) {
        clink.Text = "something";
        return;
      }

      var clabel = c as Label;
      if (clabel != null) {
        clabel.Text = "something";
        return;
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as Dan Tao's answer - just styled for minimum clumsiness.

```
foreach(Control c in dic.Keys)
{
  HyperLink clink = c as Hyperlink; 
  if (clink != null)
  { 
    clink.Text = "something";
    continue;
  } 

  Label clabel = c as Label; 
  if (clabel != null)
  { 
    clabel.Text = "something";
    continue;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the Text is a property of Control, it's more clear if you specify it in separate statements. I wouldn't try to combine them simply because they both use the word "Text" to define the property.